# Sending route parameter in form

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying create form (defined like this: [link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)) but I dont know what is `$user->id` in syntax

```
echo Form::open(array('route' => array('route.name', $user->id)))
```

When I use it I have error:

```
Undefined variable: user (View: ...)
```

Could anyone explain ?

Comment: you are using $user->id in your form, to use in that way you need to pass $user variable from your controller or you need to use   Auth::user()->id   instead of that. Your $user is not defined in this view because you are not passing data from your controller as $user to this form view.

Comment: Could you please explain what route you are trying to call this from? Are you passing user to the view?

Comment: First. fetch the user from the db inside your controller and then you can send user inside view in your controller like this:
return view('your-view', compact('user'));

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I see my a way of thinking was wrong. The problem to solve is in my route: `Route::post('page-edit/{slug}', 'PageController@postSavePage');` becouse I have error: `Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: page-edit/{slug}]. (View: /var/www/html/CMS/resources/views/admin/pages/page-edit.blade.php)` thats I tried resolve it in Form.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should pass your user to the view:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('your-view-name')->with('user', Auth::user());
}
```